# Connecting angular server from external network

Tags: angular, macos, networking, server

I set up a server in my MacBook with the following command:

```
ng serve --host 123.123.1.123
```

Now I can browse my website through `123.123.1.123:4200` from both my MacBook and desktop because they are using the same local network.

I would like to know if I can do some configuration so that someone from an external network can also browse the website in my angular server? Thank you for your help!

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1374979/reaching-a-device-in-my-lan-from-the-internet) might help